# Has Olaf Scholz made any comments about the proposed Covid-19 vaccines TRIPS waiver?

Tags: covid-19, germany, wto, vaccine, intellectual-property

There have been [calls](https://www.thedailystar.net/health/disease/coronavirus/fallouts-fightback/vaccine/news/former-world-leaders-nobel-laureates-call-germany-waive-vaccine-patents-2176501) for him to personally take a stance on the matter of the proposed [TRIPS waiver](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/trips_e/pharmpatent_e.htm) for Covid-19 vaccines patents. The calls were in fact addressed to a few other potential future chancellors, but I'm restricting this question to Scholz since he appears to be the most likely new chancellor, given that SPD [seems](https://www.dw.com/en/germany-spd-greens-and-fdp-ready-to-start-formal-coalition-talks/a-59516636) posed to lead a coalition with FPD and the Greens.